# Laravel Mongodb Error

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mongodb-query

I just started converting mysql to nosql (Mongodb) and after convertion it's showing some error like this:

```
Trying to get property 'size' of non-object
```

This is the code below i used

```
class PanelController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
       $userid = Auth::user()->id;
       $users = DB::collection('Booking')->where('Uid', '>=', $userid)->get();
      return view('panel.main')->with('records',$users);
    }
}
```

In the view i'm using like this,

```
@foreach ($records as $rec)
{{ $rec->size }}
@endforeach
```

So please someone can help me with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Before using collection() i were doing the code like this: $users = DB::table('Booking')->where('Uid', '>=', $userid)->get();

Comment: when i used {{ dd($records[0]['SIZE']); }} it works so is there any other workaround to fix this instead of changing all the code in my program?

Comment: Laravel and Eloquent do not support MongoDB by default. Are you using a third-party package to provide that integration?

Comment: Alright, Yes i'm using 3rd party package : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb.

I fixed the issue by converting the variable which was in array format to object formart with single line of code while returning the variable.